# How to live our life?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

It is said in Bhagavad Geeta, that we should live our life according to scriptural injunctions.
What scriptures should we follow exactly?
Where are the regulated principles laid out?

Comment: this is a very broad question.. in Kali Yuga, to start with, chant Bhagavan's names (Krishna, Rama, Govinda) continuously.

Comment: They are laid out in the Gita itself. So you can start with that.

Comment: [Dharma Sastras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmaśāstra) provide way/rules of living.

Comment: They are surely not Dharma Shāstras. Dharma Shāstras would ask you to marry your daughter at age of 14. Would you do that?

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore If Dharma Shastras run contrary to the sensibilities of modern society, that is a condemnation of modern society, not a condemnation of the Dharma Shastras.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Modern society is a result of God's will. We can't follow Dharma Shāstras today. To follow Dharma Shāstras, we need Rājtantra. Moreover people belong to which caste can be programmer is not mentioned in Dharma Shāstras, following which software industry would collapse. Dharma Shāstras are written presuming **no technological advancement** .

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore, are you able to see the ill-effects in society of NOT marrying off girls at age of 14 ? i know parents lamenting their hearts out, that their loving girl ran off with some christian or muslim or mleccha or non-dvija guy that she met in college or office, for registered marriage. once people see the tears of such parents who gave 'freedom' to their daughters, then they come to understand why shastras laid down these rules. It doesn't mean only girls are restricted freedom. Boys are asked to do same thing when they go to Acharya for guru kula (school).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59035/discussion-between-ram-and-rohit-singh-rathore).

Comment: @ram even the guardians of the Vedic culture are not willing to send their children in Gurukul...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer according to Kashmiri Shaivism because the teachings of Bhagvat Geeta are meant to unite individual consciousness to the universal consciousness which is the ultimate aim in Kashmiri Shaivism (is to unite with Śiva/universe - Shivvyāpti.) This is said in *Virupākshapañchākshikā*.

> Indeed, in the writings of the sages Shuka, Vamadeva, **Krishna**, Dadhici, and  Vainya, identity with the universe is explained to be born of the yoga of identification with the elements. ( Verse 50)

So, any scripture which are meant to unite individual consciousness to universal consciousness should be followed. i.e Shāstras teaching the methods & philosophy to unite with the ultimate reality. 
One may read Bhagvat Geeta & Upanishads with **non dual** commentaries to understand non duality which is prerequisite to unite individual consciousness to the universal consciousness. But I will cite scriptures of Kashmiri Shaivism as I'm answering according to Kashmiri Shaivism. Kashmiri Shaiva scriptures are broadly classified as

1. **Pratyabijna Shāstras** - teaches philosophy of Pratyabijna. Non dualism between Shiva & Añu. Pratyabijna Hridyam, Ishvar Pratyabijna, Shiv drishti, Tantrāloka, tantrasāra etc are some Pratyabijna Shāstras.
2. **Spanda Shāstras** - Expands content of Shiv Sutras **from the point of Shakti**. E.g, Spanda Karika or Spanda Sutras.
3. **Āgama Shāstras** - Revelation **of Shiva**. They lay down both principles & practices. E.g, Mālinivijay tantra, Svechcandra tantra, Vijnānabhairav tantra, Rudrayāmala tantra, Shiv Sutras etc. 

    
    
   **Summary verse by achārya Abhinavgupta** in his commentary on Bhagvat Geeta.

> That all merciful *Parāshakti*, which blesses all living beings, blossoms & expands in that unitary consciousness called **Brahman**; therefore, one should strive to attain that highest reality.

Comment: Don't you think that we need more practical suggestions? Just leading a righteous life is more than enough. Listen to what ur elders say have compassion for every beings, be truthful etc.. That is how we all should be living our lives.

Comment: Yes @Rickross this is how we unite individual consciousness to universal consciousness- by purifying chitta & **all**. Scriptures I've mentioned give upāye to purify chitta to become one with the Shiva. . He had asked scriptures, I've named them. There he would get both principles & practices.

Comment: @Rickross elders are not always right... We have dowry, sati, female foeticide. Thanks to elders !!

Comment: @RakeshJoshi that's a stupid comment.

Comment: @Rickross now also elders are supporting such systems ... want to see? come where i say.

Comment: Okay @Rickross I will try to quote some practical suggestions as well.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Following elders is a general advice..Its part of sadachara.. the stream of knowledge flows from one generation to the next..Now If someone's parents are criminals then obviously one should not follow them...apply ur common sense before commenting..

Comment: @Rickross you are right but when social evils rise in the society then people blindly follow them for generation. for example not letting girl child properly educated etc.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, dowry = wrong. in past, only grooms took on marriage expenses. female foeticide = wrong. any killing is wrong.
sati = wrong only if it is forced, but greatest display of chastity if voluntary.

Comment: This link might helpful https://radhe-radhe.net/life-is-not-a-express-way/