# What all should we do (which we are not doing) according to shastras?

Tags: dharma-shastras

Shastras are nothing but a set of rules which a 'manava' should follow or else he can not be termed as 'manava'. In our urban life style we skip many of these rules, so I wanted to know some of the basic ones.

Comment: Manusmriti would be a good start.

Comment: Can you explain Manusmriti

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19184/how-to-live-a-life-according-to-our-scripture/19185#19185

Comment: Eating onion, garlic,non sacrificial meat  is most common, setting toilets in wrong directions, shaving/clipping nails/hair cutting on wrong days etc.

Comment: All these are done in a proper Hindu family in urban areas, even I follow all these as these are the basics can you pointed out some of the big and sinful mistakes done by us